# sqlite select AS behavior

Tags: sqlite, select

I got a little problem with the AS in a select statement, it kinda change the type of my column from INTEGER to TEXT.

```
sqlite> drop table t;
sqlite> create table t (x integer);
sqlite> insert into t values (0);
sqlite> insert into t values (1);
sqlite> insert into t values (2);
sqlite> insert into t values (3);
sqlite> insert into t values (1010);
sqlite>
sqlite> .mode column t
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select printf('%d',x) from t order by x desc;
printf('%d',x)
--------------
1010
3
2
1
0
```

The sort is OK now renaming the Col to get a better header.

```
sqlite> select printf('%d',x) as x from t order by x desc;
x
----------
3
2
1010
1
0
```

The sort is no good anymore, like if doing AS make nx become a TEXT ?

Quoting don't help

```
sqlite> select printf('%d',x) as 'x' from t order by x desc;
x
----------
3
2
1010
1
0
```

Unless you stick something in the AS like this

```
sqlite> select printf('%d',x) as 'x ' from t order by x desc;
x
----------
1010
3
2
1
0
```

Is that the expected behavior ?

Thanx for any advises
Cheers,
Phi

Answer (score 3):

Use a different name for your column alias.

```
select printf('%d',x) as y 
from t 
order by x desc;
```

Otherwise the DB can't distinguish between the column and the `printf` value you output.

Comment: Exactly. The name `as x` alias is shadowing the `x` column, causing the `order by` to sort by the output alias (a string) instead of the column (a number).

Comment: Ok didn't knew the header aliasing col name. Thx.